# I am having trouble understanding this code in Python

Tags: python, permutation

Here is the code that actually works. It returns all possible permutations of a given string of any length
**eg:** `Permutations('ab') returns ['ab','ba]`

```
def permutations(string):
  if len(string) == 1: return set(string)
  first = string[0]
  rest = permutations(string[1:])  #This is the line that i do not understand
  result = set()
  for i in range(0, len(string)):
    for p in rest:
      result.add(p[0:i] + first + p[i:])
  return result
```

I do not know what the line(commented above) `rest = permutations(string[1:])` is doing.
I tried writing it like this `rest = string[1:]`, however it doesn't work properly when written like this.

What is the difference between these two lines of code?

```
rest = permutations(string[1:])
```

and

```
rest = string[1:]
```

it seems to be calling itself inside the function but i am unsure as to how that would make a difference.

Comment: It is a recursively calling permutations function on sliced string. string[1:] means slice of string[start:end]. Here is the nice reading material on slices https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings#string-slices

Answer (score 0):

It's doing a [recursion](http://geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/), a popular concept in programming. In every iteration, it calls the same function with a new string as argument which you obtain after [slicing](https://realpython.com/lessons/string-slicing/) "string[1:]"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I appreciate the response, it helped a lot!